# How do I tie into the standard input and output with C#?

Tags: c#, input

What I am trying to do is see if I can use the MinGW C++ compiler and debugger to compile files using a C# app. I want to be able to read the output and write to the input (input mainly for the debugger) within the C# app whenever I need to.

Reading from output will be much like Visual Studio does in its 'Output' window durring a project build.

I have used `System.Diagnostics.Process` before but haven't been able to figure out how to interact with the processes.

So, how do I take control of std input/output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Redirecting standard input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx)

[Reading standard output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The following question shows how to capture standard output:

[How do I run a Console Application, capture the output and display it in a Literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122306/how-do-i-run-a-console-application-capture-the-output-and-display-it-in-a-litera/5122425#5122425)

Writing to standard input is similar -- set RedirectStandardInput to true, and use a streamwriter to write to it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx