# Can I embed the output of a program in a web application in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a web app that will use a server executable to do all the work. The program is in DOS. I want to embed the output of the program in the page. I've done this in PHP, but I'm new to ASP.net and C#. I need some native functions that can call and embed the program in the site. The outputs are video and audio files. The program is ffmpeg (cite: [ffmpeg.org](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)).

I've been going over the Microsoft Documentation and I'm using VS17 Community. It doesn't seem to say much about adding arbitrary code into a web app produced in the languages. I'm still researching, and I thought it'd be smart to come here.

I need a way to pass the output to the Web App. The outputs are going to vary as well. So there is going to be some definitely variable embedding going on.

Comment: Ffmpeg is a DOS program? I doubt that! :D

Comment: How did you it in PHP? It will be very similar in ASP.NET. If you have files on disk - just search help for binary file download with asp.net. Or if ffmpeg can write its output to stdout, you can connect the streams and send directly. (I am not sure if this is best solution, but it is an option.) Have a look at C# documentation of starting another applications (class Process) - you will use its functionality to do most important parts of it.

Comment: @AlKepp I got it for DOS on ffmpeg.org. Thanks for the Process class idea. I'll look at that. I have a book on C# and a ASP.net book is on the way.

Comment: I can't see anything for DOS on ffmpeg.org - they provide only Mac/Linux/Windows versions. Don't you confuse terms? DOS and Windows command line?

Comment: @AlKepp Thanks for solving that for me :) Oh yea, I confuse terms all the time. I know what I'm saying and I can come across as someone on Peyote.

Comment: @AlKepp btw, can linux run ASP  and C# pages?

Comment: I bet you are also confusing ASP and ASP.NET. When you ask: Linux can run ASP.NET pages, but not ASP pages.

Comment: Could you describe the difference? That sounds so important to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a Console Application, capture the output and display it in a Literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122306/how-do-i-run-a-console-application-capture-the-output-and-display-it-in-a-liter) or [Running Command line from an ASPX page, and returning output to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247668/running-command-line-from-an-aspx-page-and-returning-output-to-page).  Also, a GUI-less Windows application != DOS.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2

This is the class that handles outside Processes. Very easy to understand.

Comment: That's quite a leap to go from "[Here's documentation for a class](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) for creating processes" to "I want to embed the output of the program in the page."  There are some critical details missing to make this a useful answer.  How do you use the `Process` class to start FFmpeg?  And how do you include the output of the FFmpeg `Process` (the console output, or the output files?  it's not clear from the question) in an ASP.NET response?